# Unable to scape this site .how to scrape using request for this particular site

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

Hello I am new to web scraping, I am using request to scrape data from this site.

site is =  https://5be03f79cd91330333769820-eha2016.my.conferences.cc/abstracts

This site downloads data and stores data in form of cookies. I need to access this data in cookies using requests.

How to access data in this website.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to access cookies like you said, you use request_object.cookies['cookieyouwant']